# how to fix django login problems

Tags: python, django

I was working on django project but I could not login into my django app after successful registration(confirmed from admin side). I have added phone number field to registration page, help me fix the login code, i am new to programming help me out please

my code looks like this:
This is my view.py

```
def register_view(request):
    """Registration view."""
    if request.method == 'GET':
        # executed to render the registration page
        register_form = UserCreationForm()
        return render(request, 'netflix/register.html', locals())
    else:
        # executed on registration form submission
        register_form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if register_form.is_valid():
            User.objects.create(
                first_name=request.POST.get('firstname'),
                last_name=request.POST.get('lastname'),
                email=request.POST.get('email'),
                phone=request.POST.get('phone'),
                username=request.POST.get('email'),
                password=make_password(request.POST.get('password'))
            )
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/login')
        return render(request, 'netflix/register.html', locals())


def login_view(request):
    #Login view.
    if request.method == 'GET':
        # executed to render the login page
        login_form = LoginForm()
        return render(request, 'netflix/login.html', locals())
    else:
        # get user credentials input
        username = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        # If the email provided by user exists and match the
        # password he provided, then we authenticate him.
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            # if the credentials are good, we login the user
            login(request, user)
            # then we redirect him to home page
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/logged_in')
        # if the credentials are wrong, we redirect him to login and let him know
        return render(
            request,
            'netflix/login.html',
            {
                'wrong_credentials': True,
                'login_form': LoginForm(request.POST)
            }
        )
```

This is my forms.py

```
User = get_user_model()


class UserCreationForm(BaseUserCreationForm):
    phone = forms.CharField(max_length=20, required=True, label="Phone number")
    firstname = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=True, label="First name")
    lastname = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=True, label="Last name")
    email = forms.EmailField(label="Email Address")
    password = forms.CharField(
        label="Password",
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=True),
        min_length=6,
        max_length=20
    )
    password_conf = forms.CharField(label="Password confirmation", widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'phone', 'password', 'password_conf')

    def clean(self):
        """Check if the form is validated."""
        # perform default validation of the form
        super(UserCreationForm, self).clean()

        # extract user input data
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        phone = self.cleaned_data.get('phone')
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        password_conf = self.cleaned_data.get('password_conf')

        # Check if the password match the password confirmation
        if password != password_conf:
            self._errors['password_conf'] = self.error_class([
                "wrong confirmation"
            ])

        # Check if the email used doen't already exist
        if User.objects.filter(username=email).exists():
            self._errors['email'] = self.error_class(['Email already exist'])

        # return any errors if found
        return self.cleaned_data
```

This is my models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    firstname = models.TextField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    lastname = models.TextField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=CHARS_MAX_LENGTH, blank=False, unique=True)
    phone = models.TextField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=CHARS_MAX_LENGTH, blank=False)`
```

Comment: Do you use a custom user model? If yes share the *full* model.

Comment: Are you sure you have `method="POST"` on the HTML form?